# Modules or new Applications?

Tags: php, yii, web-application-design, yii-modules

I've started working with Yii for a month (great Framework) and I am now going to build an application, ERP style.

The goal is to have a main application and then, according to user's roles and permissions, have the possibility to navigate (through single sign-on) to the other applications in the ERP.

I read about modules on [Yii's docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module) and although I got the idea, I was left with some doubts.

Surely it is an advantage to have a One Big application with all the branch applications the company needs as modules but what are the limitations?

Or is it preferable to create seperate entire applications instead of modules inside the main App and then navigate through sub-domains?

Answer (score 0):

Its better and preferred to have modules rather than developing separate applications. With modules you can have totally different look and feel just like a separate application. You must have used Gii tool, well that is also a module within your application.

The main advantage with modules is that you wont have to deploy it separately, it is a self contained application in your website. But again that could be a disadvantage if you need to have total separation of these applications.

To learn more about modules see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module